# c++, class member arrays not holding their value

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have a class called *opf*, which contains two arrays that are initialized in the constructor. In the main code, I create an instance of opf called *curfile* and run its member function, *testfunc()*. The variable *fnum* carries its value just fine to *testfunc*, but when I call the members of the array *ssplit* I get huge integers and I can't call the members of *flist* without having a runtime error tossed at me.

```
//in main.cpp
int main()
{
   opf curfile;
   curfile.testfunc();
}

//in opf.h
class opf
{
private:
   std::string defpath;
   bool initf;

public:
   opf();
   ~opf();

   std::string flist[9];
   int ssplit[9];
   int fnum;
   std::string path; //path including filename
      std::string filename; //just the filename

   std::vector<std::vector<std::string> > etoken; //(0, std::vector<std::string>(fnum))//all entries  in file

   std::ifstream instream; //read stream
   std::ofstream outstream; //write stream

   bool oread(std::string NIC, std::string year, std::string month);
   void dcache();
   void testfunc();
};

//in opf.c

    opf::opf()
{
   std::string flist[9];
   flist[0] = "Year"; flist[1] = "Month"; flist[2] = "Date";
   flist[3] = "Hour"; flist[4] = "Cell/Subject"; flist[5] = "Issue";
   flist[6] = "Status"; flist[7] = "Comments"; flist[8] = "Completion Date";
   fnum = sizeof(flist)/sizeof(*flist);
   defpath = "\\\\*****************\\User\\TaskTracker\\";
   int ssplit[9];
   ssplit[0] = 4; ssplit[1] = 12; ssplit[2] = 18;
   ssplit[3] = 24; ssplit[4] = 40; ssplit[5] = 80;
   ssplit[6] = 120; ssplit[7] = 145; ssplit[8] = 160;
   initf = true;
   }

opf::~opf(){}

void opf::testfunc()
{
   for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
   {
      std::cout << ssplit[i] << " ";
      std::cout << flist[i] << " ";
   }
   return;
}
```

testfunc prints the following:

1853187679 2621539 2002153829 57503856 -2 2001877146 2001876114 0 8558496 terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
what(): basic_string resize

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way.

Any advice is appreciated...

Comment: I think the problem is that you are declaring local variables with names identical to your member variables in the constructor. So in essence, your member variables are left uninitialized.

Comment: Function local variables takes "precedence" over class member variables.

Comment: thanks! I didn't realize I had done that.

Comment: How does a comment get three upvotes but none of the answers that say essentially the same thing have none?

Comment: @dreamlax: The comment obviously appeared before any of the answers...

Comment: @barakmanos: After I had submitted my answer, your comment only had 1 upvote.

Comment: @dreamlax: I think it really depends on whether or not you refresh the webpage on your browser. I saw 3 upvotes before any of the answers were present (that's why I posted it also as an answer, which I am now considering to delete).

Comment: @dreamlax All the answers say essentially the same thing. There's no reason to vote one of them higher than one of the others.

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring versions of `ssplit` and `flist` in your constructor, which shadow the member variables, so the member variables never get any data assigned to it. Simply remove the `flist` and `ssplit` declarations from your constructor so that you end up assigning values to the member variabels instead.

Answer (score 1):

the arrays you declare in constructor are local to that constructor. What you want is to initialize the member arrays of your class; simply remove `std::string flist[9];` and `int ssplit[9];` from your constructor implementation.